# Cakephp Nested Routes

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got a controller called Items and another one called Categories. Items may belong to different Categories.

The routes that I have are

```
/items
/items/:item_id
/items/categories
/items/categories/:category_id
```

And this is my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/items', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'index');
Router::connect('/items/:item_id', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('item_id')), array("item_id" => "[0-9]+"));
Router::connect('/items/categories', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/items/categories/:category_id', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', array('pass' => array('category_id')), array("category_id" => "[0-9]+"));
```

The problem is that the third route fails as it routes to the Items controller which it shouldn't.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

be careful on the order of your routes... cake will match to the first occurrence, so try using your routes like this:

```
Router::connect('/items', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'index');
Router::connect('/items/categories', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/items/categories/:category_id', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', array('pass' => array('category_id')), array("category_id" => "[0-9]+"));
Router::connect('/items/:item_id', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('item_id')), array("item_id" => "[0-9]+"));
```

good luck

Comment: you normally want to list them from lest greedy (most exact) to most greedy (eg /* [a catch all] would almost never be a first route, but has a place as the last one)

Answer (score 1):

in you config/routes.php

put a line

```
Router::connect('/items/categories', array('controller' => 'categories',
 'action' => 'index'));
```

or something similar.

it will redirect all you /items/categories to the index action of categories controller.

for admin pages (actions that use admin prefix):

```
Router::connect('/items/categories', array('controller' => 'categories',
 'action' => 'index','admin'=>true));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's actually what I have in there, but it still calls Items' view action. I'll put the routes in the question now.

Comment: Just for clarity. are these the public actions or admin actions?

Comment: Well, users log in and they see their Items and Categories.

Comment: if it's an admin pages (using admin routing) than you can specify 'admin' => true in you routes. I've added it in my post.

Comment: Thanks man. It appeared to be a problem with the routes order.